# Can I repeat fetchColumn in a function?

Tags: php, database

I'm trying to show 3 different values in 3 different column in a table. My first $results is okay, it's shows what it has to shows in my database but the second and the third doesn't show up. So tell me guys, how can I fix that problem? How can I show my 3e column and the other one?

```
public function Show($name) {
        $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM form WHERE username='$name'");
        $st->execute();
        $results = $st->fetchColumn(2);
        print("Votre adresse: $results <br>");
        $results = $st->fetchColumn(3);
        print("Votre met: $results <br>");
        $results = $st->fetchColumn(4);
        print("Votre age: $results <br>");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we cannot use fetchColumn and fetchAll multiple times..so that's why we store it in a variable and then fetch data with the help of foreach loop statement for echo all data..but try this one code may be it will be helpful for you

```
function fetch_det()
{
    $query=self::$db->prepare("select * from clas_products");
    $query->execute();
    $dta=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0); //you can enter column num 2,3,4 instead of 0 
    print_r($dta);
}
```

Comment: Saved my life. 2 days spent for understanding why my condition didn't work. Higher in my code i used `FETCH_COLUMN` for a log line. Thanks